# AVPlayer - Play from Local URL

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Surprisingly i have not been able to find an answer to this despite many searching.

I have a file that has been cached, i can retrieve the cache directory and file name which i believe to be the url?

this is code to get the file and then play it

```
let cachedFilePath = getCachedFilePath.result as! String
audioFileURL = cachedFilePath
self.audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: NSURL(string: audioFileURL!) as! URL)
```

This is what is returned if i print `audioFileURL`:

> /Users/Genie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2FB00CE-B018-4FDF-9635-35FD6678DF8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/E18B5E89-B973-4277-AA5C-1378C69D80CD/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/7e4a8fc0eb37b655b859e4959f986da2_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2017-92.mp3

The player loads but it never plays, It just sits there spinning.  so i am wondering if i am passing the url to the player correctly?

i read on one thread to use `file://` before it but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the place where you're creating an NSURL, you have the replace the argument name `string` to `fileURLWithPath`

Change

```
NSURL(string: audioFileURL!)
```

to

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFileURL!)
```

Also, why are you casting `NSURL` to `URL` ? Why not use `URL` directly?

Answer (score 2):

try like this,i hope it will work for you.

```
self.audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFileURL!) as! URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AVPlayerItem(url:URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "mp4")!))
```

And make sure your video is added to the bundle:

`project root` > `your Target` > `Build Phases` > `Copy Bundle Resources`.